# Is there a way to increase the size (from 80 kB to 100 kB) of a pdf file without adding any new texts or images?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, size, filesize

I need to increase the file size of a pdf without adding any new texts or images.  I can reduce the file size by compressing it. When I increase the file dimensions from A4 to A3, A2 etc using available online tools, it automatically gets compressed. What I want is to increase its size from 80 kB to 100 kB. Any idea how can it be done in Python or using any tool?

Comment: In which programming language do you want to implement that? Which PDF library do you plan to use?

Comment: @mkl maybe using some library in Python. I am not familiar with PDF editing libraries.

Comment: You might want to make that clear in your question (e.g. "Any idea how it can be done *in Python*?") and add a [tag:python] tag to your question. I'm mostly at home with Java, not with Python, though, so I cannot help here.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. I solved it, first by converting the pdf to a postscript (ps) file, then converting the ps file back to a pdf file. One can experiment with different converters. If default values do not work, one may try changing the default values of appropriate parameters. For me, the final file size became ~300 kB with default values.

1. To **convert PDF to PS**, one can use **gs**, **pdf2ps** or **pdftops**
   converter:

> pdftops initial.pdf intermediate.ps

2. To **convert PS to PDF**, one can use **gs** or **ps2pdf** converter:

> ps2pdf intermediate.ps final.pdf

**USE THIS METHOD**
As suggested by K J, it is not a good idea to convert a pdf to a ps format, because this may lead to loss of some source content. The better way to increase the file size would be to decompress the existing contents in the pdf file. One can use **mutool** for this purpose.

> mutool clean -d -a input_file.pdf output_file.pdf

One may as well refer to the following posts https://stackoverflow.com/a/25377929/10802527 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/25377913/10802527

Comment: Yes, decompression with mutool worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Photoshop, Open the PDF in it and do "save as" and you will see a quality option then just increase it to the max...
If it doesn't work with PDFs then take a screenshot of the PDF and do the above suggestion again, it'll work